# setting up Reactjs in Django project

Tags: django, reactjs

I am building project with react in django. 
Hierarchy of the Django project:

```
-library
 -assets
 -library
 -frontend
 -manage.py
```

I have created production_settings.py in the same direction as settings.py is.

when I run the command below i just got an error that :

```
Error reading /Desktop/Library/library/webpack-stats.prod.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

command :

```
 python3 manage.py runserver --settings = library.production_settings
```

production_settings.py:
    from .settings import *

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
]

 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

 WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-   stats.prod.json'),}}
```